# Adressing for-loops in big O notation

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, data-structures

I have the Following Loops:

n = 2^M

```
for(int i = n; i > 0; i--){
 for(int j = 1; j < n ; j*=2){
  for(int k = 0 ; k < j ; k++){
  }
 }
}
```

Im trying to understnad how to approach this, i have tried to break it down to single steps but with no luck. if someone can explane me how to look at this and what to look for in this type of question.

Comment: from where h comes from?

Comment: What's the question? This is very sloppy.

Comment: sorry the h was a mistake, i have corrected it, the question is how to i annalize it with big O notation, run time T(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just instrument it, to see what happens?

for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] bb = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; //try other values here like 1,10,100
    for (int b : bb) {
        int n = (int) Math.pow(2, b);

        int l1 = 0;
        int l2 = 0;
        int l3 = 0;

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            l1++;
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2) {
                l2++;
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    l3++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(b+" "+l1+" "+l2+" "+l3);
    }

}
```

you'd have something like

```
1 2 2 2
2 4 8 12
3 8 24 56
4 16 64 240
5 32 160 992
6 64 384 4032
7 128 896 16256
8 256 2048 65280
9 512 4608 261632
10 1024 10240 1047552
```

what does it seem?

[image]

Comment: This is a bit overwhelming, any way you can simplify that for me im still new to this matirial.